# Auto-resize of a Facebook app iframe not working

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to resize my facebook app to the full height of its content. Currently I'm using this code:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: '{APP ID}',
    appSecret: '{APP SECRET}',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    version: 'v2.11',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
  });

  FB.Canvas.setSize();
  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(7);
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId={APP ID}';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

```css
body,
iframe {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

iframe {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="fb-root">
    <iframe src="{ANOTHER FRAME}"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

But unfortunately the content is still bigger than the actual iframe so I have to scroll in the iframe to get all content.

The width is good but the height is the problem.

Would be very nice if someone could help me with this.

Comment: You’re aware that this is for Canvas/Page Tab apps only, right?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I know this. Forgot to say that my app is a page tab app.

Comment: Most likely your code trying to call the method does not get executed at all, because the `fbAsyncInit` event is not firing in the first place. When you pass “parameters” in the hash part of the SDK URL, then it will automatically initialize itself upon load using those; `fbAsyncInit` does not fire an more in that case.

Comment: (And that the app secret does not belong into client-side code, should be obvious. Remove it!)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the hint. I've changed it and now the function gets fired but it's still not working. The tab app is exactly 820x800px. Are those maximum values? Or can I create bigger apps?

Comment: No, going higher should not be a problem per se. Question is, whether the SDK is able to figure out the correct height of your app. Just to be clear, you have an iframe in your own page here? Width and height are set to auto via CSS, so that should only result in a default iframe size of 300x150px - unless that iframe itself also dynamically adapts to _its_ content height somehow?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! Got the problem solved with your question.. But now I've an another problem. The frame gets bigger but not small I the content get's smaller. So a big empty space is under the iframe. Could this also be fixed with a specific function? It's not very important...

Comment: The `setAutoGrow` method really only _grows_ the canvas. (My guess, deliberate decision by Facebook, to avoid their parent page changing height all the time if apps display content of massively different heights.) If you want to _reduce_ the size, then you have to call `setSize` yourself to set a lower size.

Comment: 7 is a bit low as parameter for the autogrow function, i would suggest increasing it (a lot)